# Find variations of numbers

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm sorry I don't know what's the proper title for this because I don't know what topic this question falls into.

So for example there are 5 people. They want to stay in a hotel. This hotel only allows at most 2 lodgers per room and at least 1. That means there are a few possible variations for this.

- 1-1-1-1-1 (1 room for each person)
- 1-2-2 (1 person stays alone, the other 4 are divided into 2 room)
- 1-1-1-2 (... and so on)

What is the algorithm to find these variations?

Comment: Is order significant? Or is 1-1-1-2 considered the same as 2-1-1-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a combinatorial question, and the abstract version is typically called balls & bins. A key question is whether the balls are distinguishable. Ditto for the bins.

In your example, the balls are people and the bins are rooms. If the rooms are distinguishable, you'll also need the total number available.

Let's say neither is distinguishable. Then the only question is how many pairs we have, with the options being 0, 1, or 2, so there are 3 solutions.

If people are distinguishable but not rooms (balls but not bins), then we care who are in the pairs. In this case 1-1-1-1-1 has a single solution, 1-1-1-2 has choose(5,2) = 10 solutions (all the ways we can choose who is in the lone pair), and 1-2-2 has choose(5,2) * choose(3,2) / 2 = 10 * 3 = 30 solutions (choose who is in the first pair, then the second, then divide by 2 to avoid double-counting where the order is reversed). Total solutions: 41.

If people and rooms are both distinguishable, then for each of the solutions above we care which room each person or pair goes in. This will depend on the total number of rooms available. If there are R rooms available, then a solution which uses r rooms where rooms aren't distinguishable will need to be multiplied by R!/(R-r)!.

E.g. 1-1-1-2 has 10 solutions where rooms are indistinguishable. If the hotel has 5 rooms then we multiple that by 5!/(5-4)! = 120 to get 1200 solutions.

If the people are a,b,c,d,e and there are 5 rooms numbered 1,2,3,4,5, then the solutions where b+d are paired up, a is in room 1, and c is in room 2 are:

```
a1, c2, e3, bd4
a1, c2, e3, bd5
a1, c2, e4, bd3
a1, c2, e4, bd5
a1, c2, e5, bd3
a1, c2, e5, bd4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider above problem similar to coin change problem, where you have the sum and coins and you have to find the number of ways you can make the sum using those coins.

Here:
coins = {1,2}
sum = Number of people